# I wana write Equity Token smart contract for Multiple Companies with there Corporate Action

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, shares, erc-3643

**How can I design an equity token standard that accommodates multiple companies' corporate actions within a single contract, allowing each company to create its own token instance within the contract and exercise control over corporate actions on behalf of its token holders?

I am aware of ERC1400 and ERC3643, but I seek guidance on which standard aligns best with my requirements, particularly regarding the ability to create an instance for each company's token within a unified contract framework**